# How do I send a class from Android to SignalR

Tags: android, .net, signalr

Trying to sent a class instance from Android via SignalR to .NET core site and back.

Android class: (LatLng is google maps api defined as 'double latitude,double:longitude)

```
 @Entity
data class OtherPosition(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val uid:Int,
    val LatLng: LatLng,
    val Time:Long,
    val UserName:String,
    val UserId: String
)
```

SignalR call:

```
    fun SendPosition(group:String,position:OtherPosition){
        hubConnection.send("SendPosition","Something",position)
    }
```

Receive:

```
       hubConnection.on("ReceivePosition", { x ->
           Log.d("SignalR: Receive Position","$x ")
        }, OtherPosition::class.java)
```

On server -
C# class:

```
      public class Position
    {
        public int uid { get; set; }

        public LatLng LatLng {get;set;}
        public long Time { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class LatLng
    {
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

Hub receives message and echoes back but on the Android end the received position has all fields as null.  Looks as if the problem is with the nested class - if I replace the LatLng field with two strings at both ends then all works.  Any suggestions on either how to fix or debug this ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS the actual value received by the server is a JsonElement. SignalR does deserialize this to an instance of the required class but did NOT serialize it on sending. Simple fix was to use object rather than class name:

```
 public async Task Sendposition(string groupid, object position)
        {
            // This line only if we need access to object:
            Position op = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Position>(position.ToString());

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivePosition", position);
        }
```

Or, if the object needs to be modified before returning then this also works:

```
 public async Task SendPosition(string groupId, Position position)
        {
            //Modify position here then:
            JsonElement root = JsonDocument.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(position)).RootElement;
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivePosition", root);
        }
```